# How to imitate a lagging network condition in development environment?

Tags: performance, debugging, networking

During frontend development, we have optimized network environment, network lagging isn't an issue for developer.

But once deployed, the site receives feedback from users who are suffering from network logging. They might not receive an timed AJAX response, they might be blocked by one large script/image loading, they might not load the required JS for the site to function.

I want to test our site with bad network condition, so the question is how could we imitate bad networking in our develop environment?

Comment: Many ways, define develop environment?

Comment: Server: Nginx, PHP, MySQL; Framework: Symfony, Django; Frontend: jQuery/css3/html5

Comment: Just google for bandwidth or network simulator. You can find plenty of tools

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simulate poor bandwidth in a testing environment (Mac OS X)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984859/simulate-poor-bandwidth-in-a-testing-environment-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 1):

Use a BSD machine with [dummynet](http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/dummynet/).  dummynet is awesome and exactly what you're looking for.  You'll need a machine with two NIC's to "route" your traffic through running a BSD variant (FreeBSD, OS X).